# ReactFire - get 'Objects are not valid as a React child' when binding Firebase to React state

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to bind my data in Firebase to my react state named 'notes'(an array) with the code below following tutorials [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/react/quickstart.html):

```
var Profile = React.createClass({
  mixins: [Router.State, ReactFireMixin],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      bio: [],
      repos: [],
      notes: []
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.ref = new Firebase('https://myname-github-notetaker.firebaseio.com');
    var childRef = this.ref.child(this.getParams().username);
    this.bindAsArray(childRef, 'notes');
  },

...

});
```

And I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error:
Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {.value, .key}).
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.
```

What does it mean? Is the line `this.bindAsArray(childRef, 'notes');` not working correctly?

Comment: Are you sure the error is at `bindAsArray()`? Because that code looks correct to me. Moreover, this error is pretty common, and usualy means you're trying to include something wrong in your virtual DOM at `render()` method

Answer (score 2):

firebase return you an array of objects.
when you do this

```
{this.props.notes.map(function(note,index){
 return <li key={index}>{note}</li>
})}
```

{note} this is an object, and i think you need to loop again through object keys or use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-addons-create-fragment in your app.

Something like this

```
var addons = require('react-addons-create-fragment');
return <li key={index}>{addons(note)}</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.ref` is a bit confusing due to React's `this.refs` - also, I'm not understanding the `this.ref.child`. Based on the docs, this should work:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://myname-github-notetaker.firebaseio.com'); //may need .com/something here
this.bindAsArray(ref, 'notes');
```

Comment: this.ref is confusing, indeed. But it doesn't mean it shouldn't work. `child()` is a [Firebase's instance method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/child.html).